# how to enable SFTP port on the server

Tags: windows, networking, sftp

How can I enable sftp port on the server?

When I type the following command in the command prompt, it gives the following result:

> C:\Documents and Settings\muralik>telnet kmkhub 22
>
> Connecting To kmkhub...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed

How can I connect to sftp port ?

Comment: do you have an sftp server installed?

Comment: or openssh the normal ssh-server? This is enough.

Comment: Sftp server is not installed.. it is just windows 2008 server & i am able to connect to FTP.. but i am unable to connect to SFTP

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't support SFTP by itself. You'll need some third party software installed to support SFTP.

Comment: presently, i am using the FTP protocol to connect to the server & I am using the 3rd party software (webdrive) to connect the end users to map my server as harddisk.. can you please provide , what third party software to be installed & it is able to communicate to the enduser..

Comment: There's a decent list on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SFTP_server_software which can provide you a good starting point.  The users will need an FTP client which supports SFTP as well, which the native FTP command line tool doesn't. I don't think that IE supports SFTP either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to run a SSH/SFTP server on your Windows box; you may want to take a look at **Syncplify.me Server** for that, it's solid and there is a free version for personal use. Read more here: http://www.syncplify.me/products/server/

Once the server is installed and configured, you need to access it using a client that "speaks" the proper protocols, therefore **not via telnet**.

Since you're talking about SFTP specifically (guessing you're only interested about file transfer and not remote shell) then I would recommend you to **try out WinSCP**.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can configure a portion of the CYGWIN software to act as an SSH server....allowing user to sftp into that server.  Yes, it runs the ssh server as a windows service.